# Как правильно связать порты VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox

Перебросил порты:

```
#!/bin/bash

VBoxManage setextradata x "VBoxInternal/Devices/pcnet/0/LUN#0/Config/ssh/Protocol" TCP
VBoxManage setextradata x "VBoxInternal/Devices/pcnet/0/LUN#0/Config/ssh/GuestPort" 22
VBoxManage setextradata x "VBoxInternal/Devices/pcnet/0/LUN#0/Config/ssh/HostPort" 2222
```

При запуске машины получаю ошибку:

```
VMSetError: Unknown error creating VM
ERROR [COM]: aRC=NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005) aIID={...} aComponent={Console} aText={Configuration error: Failed to get the "MAC" value (VERR_CFGM_VALUE_NOT_FOUND).
Unknown error creating VM (VERR_CFGM_VALUE_NOT_FOUND)} aWarning=false, preserve=false
Power up failed (vrc=VERR_CFGM_VALUE_NOT_FOUND, rc=NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0X80004005))
```

Что не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В настройках сети virtualbox должен быть указан сетевой адаптер, соответствующий pcnet. Скорее всего это не так.

Comment: Было Intel PRO, стало PCnet. Все работает.